# Using radiobuttons in ng-repeat, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with options where I want the user to be able to choose one option.

This are my options:

```
 $scope.licenses = [...]
```

This is the selected option:

```
 $scope.selectedLicense = $scope.licenses[0];
```

And in my markup I have:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lic in licenses">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedLicense" value="lic"></input>
                {{lic.nrOfLicenses}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But no radiobutton is selected at start.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9765/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `ng-repeat` directive creates child scope for each and every iteration

check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> Each template instance gets its own scope

so when repeating there is a scope variable called `selectedLicense` in each and every child scope. so your `$scope.selectedLicense` not bind to the `radio` buttons as expected.

here you can use prototypical inheritance, here is the great answer for what is [JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

```
$scope.x = {};
$scope.x.selectedLicense = $scope.licenses[0].nrOfLicenses;

<input type="radio" ng-model="x.selectedLicense" ng-value="lic.nrOfLicenses"></input>
// here angular search the `selectedLicense` in the child scope and then it will search the x object in parent scope after it detect there is no `selectedLicense` in the child scope.
```

here is the [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gwrcLhb/)

---

in the above example radio buttons are bind to the `nrOfLicenses` property in the object.

if you want to bind the `radio` to the whole object, then follow this

```
$scope.x = {};
$scope.x.selectedLicense = $scope.licenses[0];

<input type="radio" ng-model="x.selectedLicense" ng-value="lic"></input>
```

here is the [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qenc8kw7/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ng-value directive instead of value, this lets you use your scope object.

```
<input type="radio" name="license" ng-model="selectedLicense" ng-value="lic"></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kqp2v46/

Comment: how do u get the model value ?